# How to properly delete row in JTable with double click?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Good afternoon guys, i'm trying to learn java programming and then i'm encountering some problem that i don't know why with my code when I'm learning about JTable.

So, what I'm trying to do is when i double clicked the row in JTable named TableGejala, the row that i double clicked will transfered into the other JTable named TableAturan and after that the row that i double clicked in TableGejala will be removed. For the part of transferring row from TableGejala to TableAturan successfully transferred when i double clicked the row, but it doesn't delete the correct row in TableGejala. Instead of deleting the row that i clicked, it delete the row below it.

For more details, this is my code to create TableGejala :

```
private void getTableGejala() {
        while(tabel2.getRowCount() > 0){
            for(int i=0;i < tabel2.getRowCount();i++){
                tabel2.removeRow(i);
            }
        }

        tabel2.addColumn("ID Gejala");
        tabel2.addColumn("Nama Gejala");

        TabelGejala.setModel(tabel2);
        TabelGejala.setAutoResizeMode(TabelGejala.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    }
```

And then this is my code to get data for my table from MySQL :

```
    private void loadDataGejala(Boolean baru){
    tabel2.getDataVector().removeAllElements();

    try {
        java.sql.Connection konek = (Connection) Koneksi.KoneksiDB.getConnection();
        java.sql.Statement konek_statement = konek.createStatement();
        String query_bukaTabel = "";
        if(baru){
            query_bukaTabel = "select id_gejala,nama_gejala from gejala";
        }
        else{
            String idPkt = FieldID.getText();
            query_bukaTabel = "select gejala.id_gejala,gejala.nama_gejala from gejala where gejala.id_gejala not in(select id_gejala from aturan2 where id_penyakit='"+idPkt+"')";
        }

        java.sql.ResultSet line_result = konek_statement.executeQuery(query_bukaTabel);
        while (line_result.next()) {
            Object[] getO = new Object[2];
            getO[0] = line_result.getString("id_gejala");
            getO[1] = line_result.getString("nama_gejala");
            tabel2.addRow(getO);
        }
        line_result.close();
        konek_statement.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {} 
}
```

This is my code to transfer the row and delete the row :

```
    private void TabelGejalaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         

    if (evt.getClickCount()>=2){
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;
        row = TabelGejala.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        col = TabelGejala.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        String col1 = (String)TabelGejala.getValueAt(row, 0);
        String col2 = (String)TabelGejala.getValueAt(row, 1);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TabelAturan.getModel(); 
        DefaultTableModel old = (DefaultTableModel) TabelGejala.getModel();
        old.removeRow(row);
        model.addRow(new Object[]{col1, col2, 0});
        TabelAturan.requestFocus();
        TabelAturan.setRowSelectionInterval(TabelAturan.getRowCount()-1,TabelAturan.getRowCount()-1);        
        TabelAturan.editCellAt(TabelAturan.getRowCount()-1,2);
    }
}
```

And this is the screenshot of my problem :

[Before Double Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y6lg.png)

[After Double Clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SA7Zw.png)

Which part that makes my output get the wrong row to be deleted? please help me, and thank you in advance for any helps, even for reading my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly disable cell editable property in your first table(TabelGejala) to ensure proper deleting of row. I achieved this using the following code :-

```
//instance table model
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},
            new String[]{
                "ID Gejala", "Nama Gejala"
            }) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            //all cells false
            return false;
        }
    };

    TabelGejala.setModel(tableModel);
```

then use jtable.getselectedrow() and jtable.getselectedcolumn() to get values from table. after addition of desired values to second table, simply delete the selected row. here is the code, derived from your code :-

```
private void TabelGejalaMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (evt.getClickCount() >= 2) {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) TabelAturan.getModel();
        DefaultTableModel old = (DefaultTableModel) TabelGejala.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{TabelGejala.getValueAt(TabelGejala.getSelectedRow(), 0), TabelGejala.getValueAt(TabelGejala.getSelectedRow(), 1), 0});
        old.removeRow(TabelGejala.getSelectedRow());

        TabelAturan.requestFocus();
        TabelAturan.setRowSelectionInterval(TabelAturan.getRowCount() - 1, TabelAturan.getRowCount() - 1);
        TabelAturan.editCellAt(TabelAturan.getRowCount() - 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: AAAH I SEEE! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: wow, I was surprised how you implement the override method. It is blowing my mind.